# POST other Form objects on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple forms as below. The page is dynamic, I cannot say how many forms will be presented inside.

```
<form name="f1" action="submit.php" method=POST>
<input type="hidden" name="approve1" value="93545" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit/>
</form>

<form name="f2" action="submit.php" method=POST>
<input type="hidden" name="approve2" value="93545" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit/>
</form>

.....

<input type="button" value="Submit All"/>
```

When i click "**Submit All**" the values of all the forms - approve1, approve2, in the example - should be submitted in the page.

Any help with Jquery or Javascript is appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible for you to show us what you have tried?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: i am able to do it with the help of javascript by running a loop for know fixed set of form count. but i am unable to submit it; Also i am unable to find the logic for dynamic submit

Comment: @Jay : I am happy with new page load. but it should happen only once and i need to capture all data of different forms. how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To submit all the inputs at once, you'll have to create a new `<form>`.
This can be done dynamically using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitAll").click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var newForm = $("<form action='/echo/html/' method='POST'></form>");
        $("form input[type='hidden']").each(function(i, e) {
            newForm.append(
                $("<input type='hidden' />")
                    .attr("name", e.name)
                    .attr("value", e.value)
            );
        });
        $(document.body).append(newForm);
        newForm.submit();
    });
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alancnet/xK4L8/)

However, I'd recommend a different approach. Your submit buttons can carry all the information you need in a single form.

```
<form name="f1" action="submit.php" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="approve" value="93545">
        Approve 1
    </button>
    <button type="submit" name="approve" value="12345">
        Approve 2
    </button>
    <button type="submit" name="approve" value="93545,12345">
        Approve All
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: how can i read it in the form submission page with the fiddle example ?

Comment: In Chrome, you can go to your developer tools, Network, and select the last request when you click Submit. The details will be under **Request Header**

Comment: Thanks. But how can i use it for processing in submit page. As same i dont know how many approve hidden types coming  in the submit page. Please suggest; `Submit Page is a PHP`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not a PHP programmer, but if you use my second example, you'll receive ALL the approval IDs in a single field: `approve`. You can do a string split (like `"1,2".split(",")` in JavaScript) and loop through that.

Comment: I can not use second example as each form should act separately. In whatsoever language, how will you handle the submit page in this scenario ?

Comment: Then in your example, I would still change all the `name`s to "approve". If you click a single approval, you'll see '93545' in your post data. If you click Approve All, you'll see '93545,12345'. Either way, split by comma, and loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48604/discussion-between-logan-and-alancnet)

Comment: I tried it in my page. The page is not submitting. nothing is happend upon submit